# T-Sql query to clean up varchar column

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, string

I have a `varchar` column in one of my tables with data like:

```
1234abc
1234abcde456757
1234abc Supervisor
1234abc456 Administrator
```

I want to "clean it" by removing any letters and numbers immediately following them so for the above examples I want to have:

```
1234
1234
1234 Supervisor
1234 Administrator
```

In another word, I want to keep the initial number and the last word. I'm using the `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` but those functions remove everything till the end of the string and I don't know the length of the part I need to remove.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Is the initial number part always going to be 4 digits long?

Comment: No. I don't know the length of the inital part.

Comment: my set based solution is better than a loop and handles any number of digits as well as no digits, no words, or multiple words only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (RowValue varchar(50))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1234abc')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1234abcde456757')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1234abc Supervisor')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1234abc456 Administrator')

UPDATE @YourTable
    SET RowValue=LEFT(RowValue,4)+RIGHT(RowValue,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(RowValue)))
    FROM @YourTable

SELECT * FROM @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowValue
--------------------------------------------------
1234
1234
1234 Supervisor
1234 Administrator

(4 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT:  set based any number of digits and handles no digits or no words**

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (RowValue varchar(50))
set nocount on
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('13')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1234abc')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1234abc')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1234abcde456757')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1234abc Supervisor')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1234abc456 Administrator')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1234567abc456 Administrator')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Administrator')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('abcde Administrator')

set nocount off

;WITH Digits AS
(SELECT 0 AS Digit UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9

)
,Numbers AS
(SELECT 1 AS Number
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Number+1 FROM Numbers where Number<1000
)
,FindDigits AS
(
SELECT
    y.RowValue,n.Number,SUBSTRING(y.RowValue,n.Number,1) AS CharOf,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(y.RowValue,n.Number,1) LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 'N' ELSE 'A' END AS TypeOf
    FROM @YourTable         y
        INNER JOIN Numbers  n ON 1=1
    WHERE n.Number<=LEN(y.RowValue)
)
,LenOf AS
(
SELECT 
    RowValue,MIN(Number)-1 AS Digits
    FROM FindDigits
    WHERE TypeOf='A'
    GROUP BY RowValue
    HAVING MIN(Number)-1>0
UNION
SELECT 
    f.RowValue,LEN(f.RowValue)
    FROM FindDigits f
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FindDigits f2 WHERE f.RowValue=f2.RowValue AND TypeOf='A')
)
UPDATE y
    SET RowValue=CASE WHEN l.Digits IS NOT NULL THEN LEFT(y.RowValue,l.Digits)+RIGHT(y.RowValue,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(y.RowValue)))
                      WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(y.RowValue))=0 THEN y.RowValue
                      ELSE RIGHT(y.RowValue,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(y.RowValue))-1) END
    FROM @YourTable       y
        LEFT JOIN LenOf   l ON y.RowValue=l.RowValue
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)

SELECT * FROM @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
RowValue
--------------------------------------------------
13
1234
1234
1234
1234 Supervisor
1234 Administrator
1234567 Administrator
Administrator
Administrator

(9 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This assumes the number of initial digits is four, not sure if that's the case!

Answer (score 6):

You could search for the first non-digit and the first space in a subquery.  That also works if the number of digits isn't exactly four:

```
declare @t table (col1 varchar(50))
insert into @t select '12abc'
union all select '1234abcde456757'
union all select '1234abc Supervisor'
union all select '1234abc456 Administrator'
union all select '123456abc456 Administrator'

select  case when FirstNonDigit = 0 then col1
             when FirstSpace = 0 then substring(col1, 1, FirstNonDigit-1)
             else substring(col1, 1, FirstNonDigit-1) + 
                  substring(col1, FirstSpace, len(col1) - FirstSpace + 1)
             end
from    (
        select  patindex('%[^0-9]%', col1) FirstNonDigit
        ,       patindex('% %', col1) FirstSpace
        ,       col1
        from    @t
        ) subqueryalias
```

-->

```
12
1234
1234 Supervisor
1234 Administrator
123456 Administrator
```

Comment: Thanks.  Also works when the value is just a string like "Administrator" with no numbers or spaces.  I did not know that the table had such values, but aparently it did.

Comment: doesn't work for values like `Administrator` (you get a leading space) or `abc456 Administrator` (get a totally blank value)

Answer (score 0):

You actually want two strings, the characters at indices 0-3 and those from the position after the space till the end of the string. I (think) this will work (have not tried it):

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = SUBSTRING(ColumnName,1,4) + 
    SUBSTRING(ColumnName,CHARINDEX(' ',ColumnName)+1,LEN(ColumnName))
```

Comment: this does not work, CHARINDEX's first param is the string to find not he string to search, you have `CHARINDEX(ColumnName,' ')`, see [CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx), not to mention you find the first space not the last

Comment: @KM fixed CHARINDEX.  I thought based on OP's question it was reasonable to assume that there was only one space in the data.

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses a "tally table" of values to find the first non-numeric character and the last space. KM's solution using `PATINDEX` is probably more elegant!

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
   c VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES('1234abc');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('1234abcde456757');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('1234abc Supervisor');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('1234abc456 Administrator');

WITH Tally AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[id]) AS i
   FROM sys.sysobjects s1 CROSS JOIN sys.sysobjects s2 CROSS JOIN sys.sysobjects s3
), 
NumPart AS
(
   SELECT c, MIN(i) AS firstNonNumber
   FROM @t CROSS JOIN Tally
   WHERE i <= LEN(c)
   AND SUBSTRING(c, i, 1) < '0' OR SUBSTRING(c, i, 1) > '9'
   GROUP BY c 
),
SpacePart AS
(
   SELECT c, MAX(i) AS spacePos
   FROM @t t CROSS JOIN Tally
   WHERE i <=  LEN(c)
   AND SUBSTRING(c, i, 1) = ' '
   GROUP BY c
)
UPDATE t
SET t.c = LEFT(n.c, n.firstNonNumber - 1) + 
   CASE WHEN ISNULL(s.SpacePos, 0) > 0 THEN 
      RIGHT(n.c, LEN(n.c) - s.SpacePos + 1) 
   ELSE 
      ''
   END
FROM @t t
INNER JOIN NumPart n ON t.c = n.c
LEFT JOIN SpacePart s ON n.c = s.c;

SELECT * FROM @t;
```